# how to protect php files

Tags: php, security

We're making a system as a group, and I'm the lead programmer. And I don't want that one of my group members will be able to steal my code and brag to others that they're the one who made it. Is there any technique that I could employ so that the code will be disarrange or encrypted or anything so that I'm the only one who could read the codes or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, cos thats a great way to work as a team....

Comment: Sounds like your team has serious trust issues. That's most likely the real problem.

Comment: @Rob ha ha ha... that was a good one.

Comment: @Philip I think I see the problem, and I don't think it's the rest of his team... Seriously, learning *basic* programming principles first before adopting the moniker of lead programmer. This question is naive on many levels.

Comment: *sigh* Just total, complete and utterly *sigh* =P

Comment: I didn't realise that PHP was now taught in kindergarten.

Comment: If you are the lead programmer, it would be natural for you to have a lot of influence over the development process. Meaning that you can control the environment and make necessary changes to counteract the malicious behaviour of others. But on the other hand I may have misunderstood the meaning of lead programmer in your case.

Comment: A development Team is there to get the Job done in the best way possible, you sound like a jealous Team Leader. You should be concerned in getting the project done and not hold a contest of who wrote the coolest code. I think you need to become a Gardener or something. Try sub versions

Answer (score 15):

If you want to prevent people from telling "others that they're the one who made it", then you could use a source control system. They attribute an author to each commit, so there's no ambiguity over who created which piece of code.

Comment: +1 - Practical, sensible advice that deals with the problem, however misguided it may be...

Comment: I was considering - cringingly -  suggesting using something like Zend Guard (which of course it would be a terrible idea to use in this instance) but this answer was a good catch.

Answer (score 4):

There was a similar question a few weeks back. The major trend in answers was, forget it. If you can trust your team that little, you need a new team.

Edit: Found it by [**searching Google for the accepted answer**](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&safe=off&q=%22Build+a+team+you+can+trust%22+stackoverflow&aq=f&oq=%22Build+a+team+you+can+trust%22+stackoverflow&fp=cd30da993b677fa5), which I remembered :)

Comment: its really bad that one of my team members are friends with my rival. And it sucks when he gets access to what I have done, and I don't have access to what he's up to.

Comment: @user225269 GROW UP, you sound like a baby! If it's a contest of who's the best then find another job maybe a wrestler

Answer (score 3):

Use a [distributed revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) (like [git](http://git-scm.com/)), every commit is associated with a committer. And it's easier to work in a team anyway.

If you're the lead programmer, assign tasks to your other team members. Why should a programmer commit large amounts of code to module A, if he is supposed to work on module B?

And last but not least: If the lead programmer distrusts his own team this much, there should be a new team, a new lead programmer, or both!

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you need to change teams, but on a completely different note: How about going Open Source with your Project using something like [**Github**](http://github.com/)?

That way, nobody could steal each other's credit because every commit is made by name. Plus, there is no stealing of code because it's public anyway.

Comment: Not always possible if you're an employee of a company - it'll be their choice whether to keep it proprietary or not.

Comment: @Rob I'm 100% sure the OP is not lead developer in a *company*. This sounds like a team of teenage programmers to me. I would be very surprised to learn otherwise.